# How to use result set of one sub query in other sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT 
    ec.id, 
    ec.name, 
    gecr.Group_Id, 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) 
        FROM containers c 
        WHERE c.group_id IN (
                    SELECT g.ID AS Group_id FROM (group_master g) 
                    INNER JOIN group_user_reln gur ON g.ID = gur.group_id
                    WHERE gur.user_id =  91))
        AS group_count
    FROM 
        exam_category ec 
    INNER JOIN 
        group_exam_category_reln gecr ON gecr.Exam_category_Id = ec.ID 
    WHERE 
        ec.InActive_YN =  'N' 
        AND gecr.Group_Id IN 
        (SELECT g.ID AS Group_id FROM (group_master g) 
    INNER JOIN group_user_reln gur ON g.ID = gur.group_id
    WHERE gur.user_id =  91) 
    GROUP BY ec.id
    ORDER BY ec.name asc
```

In the above query how can I use sub query to get the group ids only once?

Comment: Does it have to be a subquery? What's wrong with a join?

Comment: You want to avoid multiple uses of a sub query `SELECT g.ID AS Group_id FROM (group_master g)` ?

Comment: I think this could be done with the `with` clause of SQL. shame MySQL does not support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable as table

```
   DECLARE @ids TABLE (id INT)
```

fill this table with data

```
  INSERT INTO @ids SELECT g.ID AS Group_id FROM (group_master g)
```

Use it in your query. This is a TSQL syntax, but should similarly work in MySql.